# Get the contents of an indexed file from an Index Server catalog?

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexing

Is it possible to retrieve the contents of a file from an Index Server catalog? I have tried selecting the "contents" column but it returns an empty string all the time & by reading from this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Indexing_Service_HOW-TO.aspx) i can understand that the "contents" column can queried but not retrieved!

So is there any way to get the contents using Index Server???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way out after going through the documentation of the Indexing Server. Well you can get an abstract for the contents of the indexed file by querying the "characterzation" column from the catalog. But before doing that, ensure that the registry key "GenerateCharacterization" for the catalog is set to 1. Added to this, you can set the max length of the abstract by setting the appropriate length in the reg key "MaxCharacterization". This [link](http://www.ombudsman.bc.ca/srchadm/help/reghelp.htm) might help!